# рандомный спавн на неровном terrain unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

собственно в чем проблема: как сделать рандомный спавн предметов **на поверхности неровного** террейна? так, чтобы он **не проваливался сквозь землю**, **не спавнился под землей или внутри других предметов** (деревьев, камней и пр.)? если что, игра 3d; предмет **триггерный**, и исчезает после подбора игроком, но это у меня есть уже, а вот со спавном беда. есть баганутое решение: на предмете ригидбоди, они спавнятся на большой высоте (x,z - рандом, y - фиксиров.) и падают на землю, при столкновении замораживаются и становятся триггерными (для поднятия). но иногда они почему-то либо продолжают лететь сквозь землю либо застревают на других объектах, на которые игрок не может залезть.

Comment: Если известно, что сверху ничего нет, то можно вертикально вниз с какой-нибудь высоты сделать рейкаст. И в точке пересечения с "землей" (или чуть выше) спавним что нам нужно.

Comment: на земле еще другие предметы, и рейкаст может попасть в них и заспавнить все сверху в недоступном месте(

Answer (score 0):

Нужно брать интерпалированную высоту активного terrain. Или создать места (point) где должны создаваться точки. Из этого создать массив и брать Transform о локальной расположении point.